# Repeat keystroke while key is held

Tags: keyboard, applescript, karabiner

Is there a way or a 3rd party application which would let me 'send' a keyboard input/keystroke to a game (so that it has the same effect as physically hitting the key on the keyboard rather than just repeating the letter) while I hold the key down?

So, for example, I could tell it to hit <kbd>Q</kbd> 20 times a second as long as Q is held down?

Simply, I need something like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) macOS.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I tried defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false, but I need a keyboard input 'event' happen repeatedly rather than just one input.

Comment: What's the difference? btw, you may need to reboot to toggle, I'm not sure just killing Finder will do it

Comment: It just doesn't register that way. Rather than Ooooo, I need O O O O O happen really quickly instead.

on Autohotkey I have a script
`$q::
  While GetKeyState("q","P")
  {
    Send, q
    Sleep, 200
  }
Return`

that works exactly the way I need it to. I'm just looking for the same on OS X

Comment: slow the repeat rate in prefs